# Best way to upgrade from Sitecore 8.0 Update 2 to 8.2 Update 1

Tags: upgrade, migration

I want to upgrade a Sitecore environment ( 8.0 Update 2 to 8.2 Update 1 ).
I recently went to a general Sitecore Presentation and there they mentioned that i could use a new Upgrade tool.
I found this page " https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool/ " where they mention a tool to upgrade from Sitecore 7.2 to 8.2. But it can only be done from Sitecore 7.2 with this tool it seems.
There's also for some reason a empty section about a newer version of the upgrade tool ? ( might be what i'm looking for but there is no information on it now ).

Am i looking at the wrong tool, do you know about an other way to upgrade my Sitecore version. ( Or do i not need an upgrade tool at all for this specific upgrade ? I've never done any Sitecore upgrade at this point )

Any feedback and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool currently only supports upgrading from 7.2. You'll have 2 options when it comes to upgrading:

1. Follow the standard upgrade process from Sitecore. You'll need to upgrade in order, so you'll need to follow the upgrade process to go from 8.0 update 2 to 8.1, then from 8.1 to 8.2
2. Stand up a new 8.2 instance, then migrate you current code and content from your 8.0 instance to the new 8.2 instance.

Comment: Have a read of this: http://www.seanholmesby.com/the-truth-about-sitecore-upgrades/ - the best option is to go with the update packages from Sitecore, it may take a bit longer, but makes sure that database updates to items etc... are applied properly. Those can be missed when just migrating content to a new version.

Comment: I've started upgrading the environment manually. At a certain point the upgrade manual said i should apply all changes described in the Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151003 Configuration File Changes document. This is a document of 99 pages filled with configuration changes that you need to do manually ? This feels like a joke. It would takes hours with no reassurance that everything was done right.

Comment: So I tend to take a hybrid approach to this - use the upgrade packages to upgrade your databases. Then install a fresh instance of 8.2, set the connection strings to your upgraded DB's, and deploy your code to it. That way, no config updates to make!